# Incorrect formatting when printing string

Tags: java

Attempting to create a Madlibs program that receives a `fileName` and goes through the file and looks for when `text` starts with < and ends with > .  Example being, "look at that < noun >." (ignore space between noun and <>. 
After if finds the token, it should replace it with `text = user.nextLine()`.The program works however when printing `fullText` the formatting is not the same as the .txt file. It loses the new line characters that are in the .txt file. What can be changed to ensure that the formatting is the same.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MadLibs {
  public static void main ( String [] args){
     Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file Name: ");    //file input
    String fileName = input.nextLine();

    String fileContent = readEntireFile(fileName);     //method call
    System.out.println(fileContent);
  }

  public static String readEntireFile(String fileName){
      Boolean fileOpened = true;
      File someFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);
      Scanner inputFile = null;
      String text;
      String fullText = " ";

      try{
        inputFile = new Scanner (someFile);
      }
      catch( FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
        fileOpened = false;
      }
      if(fileOpened){
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
          text = inputFile.next();
          if (text.startsWith("<") && text.endsWith(">")) {     
                    String input = text.substring(1, text.length() - 1);     
                    String word = input.replace("-"," ");
                    System.out.println("Please input a: " + word);
                    text = user.nextLine();           


          }
          fullText = fullText + text + " ";   

        }

        inputFile.close();
        return fullText;  //returns the entire String 
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "formatting is not the same"?

Comment: Maybe you lose newLine character?

Comment: @Henry When i look at the original .txt file it has skipped lines and indents, when the program prints the file those skipped lines and indents are not shown. Basically I am asking, how can i include line breaks when it prints.

Comment: use "\n" haven't seen you using a newline.

Comment: Is the original .txt file using the same line end convention as the system you are on?

Comment: @Henry I assume so, it's a normal text document.